# Using OPENSSL with PKCS11 and SoftHSM configuration engine on Mac

Tags: openssl

Currently i have an issue to setup my Mac with HSM

Current configuration

```
HSM: SoftHSM
OpenSSL, PKCS11
OS: MacOS Catalina
```

I'm using this configuration

```
openssl_conf = openssl_init

[openssl_init]
engines = engine_section

[engine_section]
pkcs11 = pkcs11_section

[pkcs11_section]
engine_id = pkcs11
dynamic_path = /usr/local/Cellar/libp11/0.4.11/lib/engines-1.1/pkcs11.dylib
MODULE_PATH = /usr/local/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so
init = 0

[ req ]
distinguished_name = req_dn

[ req_dn ]
commonName = foobar
```

Then i'm try to using this cmd for generate certification from HSM

```
OPENSSL_CONF=engine.conf openssl req -new -x509 -subj "/CN=MyCertTEST" -engine pkcs11 -keyform engine -key "pkcs11:object=mykey1;pin-value=mysecret1" -outform der -out mycert.der
```

Note: I'm already setup key into HSM

How ever seem like it show an error as

```
Error configuring OpenSSL
4569882220:error:26FFF074:engine routines:CRYPTO_internal:no such engine:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.140.1/libressl-2.8/crypto/engine/eng_list.c:367:id=dynamic
4569882220:error:26FFF066:engine routines:CRYPTO_internal:engine configuration error:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.140.1/libressl-2.8/crypto/engine/eng_cnf.c:197:section=pkcs11_section, name=dynamic_path, value=/usr/local/Cellar/libp11/0.4.11/lib/engines-1.1/pkcs11.dylib
4569882220:error:0EFFF06D:configuration file routines:CRYPTO_internal:module initialization error:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.140.1/libressl-2.8/crypto/conf/conf_mod.c:224:module=engines, value=engine_section, retcode=-1      
failed to load configuration
```

Not sure where i'm missing on configuration part or any misunderstanding the way to configuration engine

Can anyone guide me on this.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour you're seeing is most likely caused by the fact that newer macOS releases use LibreSSL by default.

You can verify this by running

```bsh
openssl version
```

in your terminal.

From your OpenSSL configuration file, I can see that you are already using `brew`, which means that you can simply install the `openssl` package and use that instead. That's what worked for me, at least.

There may also be a way to use the LibreSSL installation, but I have no idea how.